# Codeigniter, URL Routing is failing

Tags: php, codeigniter, apache2, debian

With a codeigniter codebase I've inherited, I'm attempting to get url routing up and running but it only seems to throw 404 errors.

When I go to `http://root_url/index.php` it hits the default controller/method just fine, however when I request any specifically controller/action, it 404s.

If I request `http://root_url/index.php/auth/login` apache throws

```
File does not exist: /var/www/ci_project/index.php/auth/login, referer: http://root_url/index.php
```

It looks like apache is trying to request a folder that obviously doesn't exist instead of supplying the uri segments of auth/login to the index.php

Notes:

- I'm not using any htaccess file(the codebase should work without one)
- mod_rewrite is enabled and is detected by php though I suspect the problem is occuring before hitting php
- I'm using debian(w/ apache 2.2.2) as opposed to ubuntu(2.2.14) where it does work
- Query string arguments work fine, it's just the URI segments
- I'm not attempting to remove index.php, just get the basic controller url matching working

Comment: can you share your controller and config file.

Comment: The controller file is simply the default config.php and the controller is simply the welcome controller. So with a new codeigniter install http://root_url/index.php/welcome will fail. I believe this is something to do with apache's resolution of arguments with forward-slash in it.

Comment: Try adding a `?` into the url, making it `http://root_url/index.php?/auth/login`

Comment: I think , you did wrong placement for Tank Auth library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually turned out to be an apache configuration issue on debian and nothing particularly to do with codeigniter at all.

I did a purge/re-install of apache and that appeared to fix the issue.

```
sudo apt-get purge apache2 apache2-utils apache2.2-bin apache2-common
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
```

My only guess as to why the problem occured is that I had 
the `libapache2-mod-php5filter`(which I didn't realise till purging occured) instead of the `libapache2-mod-php5` package installed and it simply didn't handle the urls correctly.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It actually turns out, it seems to be an issue installed the latest versions of apache. Simply running `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5` seems to work.